# Office 365 App Deployment Issues : The request could not be completed because of a failure of writng to DNS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, office365, sharepoint-online

I am trying to deploy Sharepoint Add-in on office 365 using visual studio 2015 and getting following error

Add-in installation encountered the following errors:
  31-08-2016 12:17:51 PM

@"Error 1 
        CorrelationId: fa58c6ca-d298-4c9a-93e5-8985bcb994c2 
        **ErrorDetail: The content database on the server is temporarily unavailable.** 
        ErrorType: Transient 
        ErrorTypeName: Intermittent
        **ExceptionMessage:** **The request could not be completed because of a failure of writng to DNS**. 
        Source: AppWeb 
        SourceName: App Web Deployment